# angular state management using a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some issues to preserve the state of a list(array) of items in an app.

The app has a component item-search that accepts a user input which is sent to an API. The API returns a list of items which is displayed as a list in the browser. I want to add the ability for the user to drill down to each item as a separate page for which I created an item-details components. I want to pass the array of items to the item-details component along with the item ID when the user clicks on a specific item so that I can query the array and find the corresponding item.

Today I use a service called item.service.ts that returns an observable to the item-seach component but it pipes the response to a local variable called elements. I was wondering if I can pass the elements variable to the item-details component or how would be the best way to pass the array to the item-details component? I would like to avoid having to for example send another API request to get a specific item if I already have the array in memory.

Project structure:
src
|
--item-search/
--->item-seach-files
--item-details/
--->item-details-files
--shared/
--->item.service.ts